Multiple vector iterator to call parent methods in c++
I have a parent class:
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void method1() = 0;                                   
    virtual void method2() = 0;  
    virtual void method3() = 0;  
};                                            

And two children (but will need to make more):
class Child1: public Parent {
    void method1() override;
    void method2() override;
    void method3() override;
};


class Child2: public Parent {
    void method1() override;
    void method2() override;
    void method3() override;
};

Inside my Controller class I have a std::vector of each class:
Class Controller{
private:
   std::vector<Child1*> childs1;
   std::vector<Child2*> childs2;
};

I want to be able to iterate through all elements of all child vectors to call the overridden methods without having to make a for loop for everyone.
Something like:
std::vector<std::vector<Parent*>> all_vectors = 
   { 
   std::vector<Child1*>(childs1.begin(), childs1.end()), 
   std::vector<Child2*>(childs2.begin(), childs2.end())
   }

for(vector<Parent*> v: all_vectors) {
    for(Parent* i: v){
       i->method1();
       i->method2();
       i->method3();
    }
}

This doesn't really work because it breaks the size of each vector. For example for a childs1.size() = 4, it iterates correctly the first 4 elements but tries to access a fifth. If asked about allvectors[0].size() or allvectors[1].size(), it gives sizes much greater than the original.
There is also the problem that this creates a bunch of copies that are not needed.
Is there a way to create a custom iterator that just goes through every all elements of n vectors? Some way that its iterator++ operation jumps from vector<Child1>.end() to vector<Child2>.begin().
Or is there a better solution I'm not seeing here?

If you have access to c++20 ranges you can make a transform view of each vector to a parent pointer range and then you just need to join all of those views together and you can iterate them and do whatever.

Initialization of all_vectors does not compile because you cannot convert from vector<Child*> to vector<Parent*>.

What you show can't work since std::vector<Parent*> can't be directly initialized from std::vector<ChildX*>, as they are two separate types. vector<X> and vector<Y> are not related to each other, even if X and Y are related.
But even if you could initialize the outer vector the way you want, your claim about the size differences of the inner vectors is incorrect.  The inner for loop would easily handle vectors of different sizes.  But you should change vector<Parent*> v to vector<Parent*>& v to avoid extra copies of each vector per iteration.
In any case, while you could certainly create a custom iterator class to handle what you want, I would instead suggest simply using a single std::vector<Parent*> that holds all of the ChildX* pointers, eg:
std::vector<Parent*> all_childs;
all_childs.reserve(childs1.size()+childs2.size());

all_childs.insert(all_childs.end(), childs1.begin(), childs1.end());
all_childs.insert(all_childs.end(), childs2.begin(), childs2.end());

for(Parent* child: all_childs) {
    child->method1();
    child->method2();
    child->method3();
}



I want to be able to iterate through all elements of all child vectors to call the overridden methods without having to make a for loop for everyone.

It seems you want to factorize the code.
You might do it the other way: create sub-functions (or lambda):
const auto call_123 = [](Parent& p){ p.method1(); p.method2(); p.method3(); };
const auto call_123_on_vec = [&](auto& v){ for (auto* p : v) { call_123(*p); };
call_123_on_vec(childs1);
call_123_on_vec(childs2);

To avoid to repeat the last function for each vectors, you might (ab)use of std::tuple:
const auto call_123 = [](Parent& p){ p.method1(); p.method2(); p.method3(); };
const auto call_123_on_vec = [&](auto& v){ for (auto* p : v) { call_123(*p); };
std::apply([&](auto&... vectors){ (call_123_on_vec(vectors), ...); },
           std::tie(childs1, childs2));

